# mapping class attributes to other (same attributes) class

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes with exactly the same named attributes (1 business class, and 1 data class).

At this moment i've written a 'convert' method that maps all the attributes van 1 class to the other:

```
private class BusinessLogic convert(Datalogic dataclass)
{
    Businesslogic businessclass = new BusinessLogic();
    businessclass.ID = dataclass.ID;
    businessclass.name = dataclass.name;
    .....
    return businessclass;
}
```

It seems to be that there must be a far more simpler way. I'm only not sure how to search for it. Can someone put me on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a task for a mapping tool, e.g. [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) - if all the properties are named the same this pretty much is a one-line since by convention they will be mapped to the corresponding property in the target class.

For your particular example that could be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Datalogic, BusinessLogic>();
BusinessLogic businessclass = Mapper.Map<Datalogic, BusinessLogic>(dataclass);
```

Comment: Wonderfull, only one question left. Where do I define the mappings if the mappings are used in a class-library?

Answer (score 2):

**AutoMapper** is a library available which does this `Object to Object` mapping for you.

With AutoMapper, Your code can be reduced to some thing like

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Datalogic , Businesslogic >();
Product product= GetProductFromDB(2);
Businesslogic productViewItem = Mapper.Map<Datalogic , Businesslogic >(product);
```

Home page: http://automapper.org/

Source: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Tutorial link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper